# C# filtering DataGridView - update row numbers in DataTable

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having a problem with updating row numbers in a filtered DataGridView control. The following code works fine when filtering the DataGridView control:

```
this.dtFiltrTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = filtr;
int rowNum = 1;
foreach (DataRowView drv in this.dtFiltrTable.DefaultView)
{
  drv.BeginEdit();
  drv[0] = rowNum++;//update row number in first column.
  drv.EndEdit();
}
```

However, when resetting the filter, this code hangs:

```
this.dtFiltrTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = null;
foreach (DataRowView drv in this.dtFiltrTable.DefaultView)
{
  drv.BeginEdit();
  drv[0] = rowNum++;//update row number in first column.
  drv.EndEdit();
}
```

Removing the BeginEdit () or EndEdit () statement does not resolve the problem.

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: What type of column are you using?  Seems like you have a TextBox Column in the DGV,  Why do you have BeginEdit?  The BeginEdit is for a user to edit the textbox and is waiting for a keyboard/mouse method.  You are simply just the value in code.

Comment: Removing the BeginEdit, EndEdit instruction changes nothing.

Comment: I tried to use the dataGridView1_RowPostPaint event but it works very slowly.

Comment: If you added a Column to show the Row index, just add `if (e.ColumnIndex == 0) e.Value = e.RowIndex.ToString();` in the CellFormatting event. Never loop the DGV rows, especially when the DGV is bound to a datasource. Otherwise, you can paint the Row index inside the RowHeader bounds, which is more common. The CellPainting event is used for that.